# Send table variable as mailto subject

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass a table variable as a mailto subject.

I am using this script to do for a div ID, but unsure how to to do this for a class - `getElementsByClassName` doesn't work. How Do I do this?

Button:

```
<button name="mail_button" onclick="mail_content()">Mail</button>
```

Script:

```
function mail_content() {
    var tableContent = document.getElementById("mailcontent").innerHTML;
    var mBody = "" + tableContent + "";
    document.location.href = "mailto:test@domain.com?subject=Titel&body=" + mBody;  
}
```

Element I wish to fect the varable from:

```
<td class="mailcontent">N7P47AA</td>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the index.Class is not unique like the id.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("mailcontent")[0].innerHTML
```

1)
 Select it via an ID that is unique.

2)
 Select it via a Class and index combination.

Here is the Docs for it:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

```js
function mail_content() {
  var tableContent = document.getElementsByClassName("mailcontent")[0].innerHTML;
  var mBody = "" + tableContent + "";
  document.location.href = "mailto:test@domain.com?subject=Titel&body=" + mBody;
}

mail_content();
```

```html
<table>
  <td class="mailcontent">N7P47AA</td>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks - It still gives me undefined for some reason.

Comment: seems to work.. Not sure why I cant get it to work on the live site. Thanks though, will fiddle around.

Comment: @user3344734 please mark the answer as correct if you agree.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing document.getElementById("mailcontent"), but the element you are looking for has no ID attribute. Currently your element has a class attribute of mailcontent, so you have 2 options:

1. Add an ID attribute to your element and give it an id of mailcontent
2. Change document.getElementById to:

   `document.getElementsByClassName("mailcontent")[0].innerHTML`

   Remember, document.getElementsByClass name returns an array, rather than a 
   single item, hence the addition of the [0] so you can get the first item in 
   the array

Comment: Thanks - It still gives me undefined for some reason.

Comment: which option did you try?

Comment: I cant give an id so the second alternative.